# How to get POST Form data into an email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, phpmailer

I am making a form for my customer to fill out when they order a product.

I am trying to make it so when they hit submit it emails the data to my email and it cc's them. The email will have styling in it. I can't figure out how to get it to put the data into the email. I am currently using PHPMailer. 

Here is the php file

```
<?php

$FirstName = $_POST['First_Name'];
$LastName = $_POST['Last_Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Company = $_POST['Company'];


$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SetFrom('No-Reply@LDSVacuum.com');
$mail->Subject = 'Request';
$mail->AddAddress('Chase.Price@LDSVacuum.com');
$mail->AddCC($Email);
$strhtml = '
<div align="center">
<font face="arial" color="#336699" size="6">
    Request
</font>
</div>
<div> 
<font face="arial" color="#336699" size="5">
    Customer Information
</font>
<p>
    <label for="fname">
        <font face="arial" color="#336699" size="4">
            First Name:
        </font>
    </label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="50">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="lname">
        <font face="arial" color="#336699" size="4">
            Last Name:
        </font>
    </label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" size="50">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="email">
        <font face="arial" color="#336699" size="4">
            Email Address:
        </font>
    </label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="50">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="company">
        <font face="arial" color="#336699" size="4">
            Company Name:
        </font>
    </label>
    <br />
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company"size="50">
</p>
</div>
';

$dochtml->loadHTML($strhtml);
$fname = $dochtml->getElementById('fname');
$fname->value=$FirstName;
$lname = $dochtml->getElementById('lname');
$lname->value=$LastName;
$email = $dochtml->getElementById('email');
$email->value=$Email;
$company = $dochtml->getElementById('company');
$company->value=$FirstName;

$mail->Body = $strhtml;

$mail->Send();

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Unknown Error has Occured. Please try again Later.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else {
    echo 'Thank You, $FirstName . We have emailed your request to Info@LDSVacuum.com . Your email $Email has been cc to the email.';
}   

?>
```

Here is the form

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" name="contactform" autocomplete="off" id="nipplerequest" action="http://localhost/emailform.php"> 
 <p>
  <label for='First_Name' class="FG3" width="157">
   <span class="red">
    *
   </span> 
   First Name:
  </label>
   <br />
  <input type="text" name="First_Name" id="First_Name" class="FG2" size="50" placeholder="John">
   <br />
  <label for='Last_Name' class="FG3">
   <span class="red">
    *
   </span> 
   Last Name:
  </label>
   <br />
  <input type="text" name="Last_Name" class="FG2" size="50" placeholder="Johnson">
   <br />
  <label for='Email' class="FG3">
   <span class="red">
    *
   </span> 
   Your Email Address:
  </label>
   <br />
  <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" class="FG2" size="50" placeholder="John_Johnson@company.com">
   <br />
  <label for='Company' class="FG3">
   <span class="red">
    *
   </span> 
   Company Name:
  </label>
   <br />
  <input type="text" name="Company" class="FG2" size="50" placeholder="Company Inc.">
   <br />
 </p>
  </form>
  <br />
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are:

1. Creating a string of HTML
2. Creating a DOM from that string of HTML
3. Modifying that DOM by setting values
4. Emailing the original string of HTML and ignoring the DOM you generated

You need to convert the DOM back into HTML (`$modified_html = $dochtml->saveHTML()`) and send that instead of your original string.

Comment: I'm Getting this error: Notice: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$saveHTML

Comment: `saveHTML()` is a method, not a property. It might help if you made the slightest attempt to read documentation.